# Wordpress: Showing only the title of post which is hovered

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on my portfolio (Wordpress, fukasawa) and I'm trying to let this work:

On the Main Page, where all the posts are, I would like to hover on one post and display the his post header. If i'm using this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

$(".posts").hover(function(){
        $(".post-header").css('opacity', '1');
   }, function(){
        $(".post-header").css('opacity', '0');
    });
  
});
```

HTML:

```
.post-header {
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

It will show all the post headers of all the posts (makes sense, right?). So somehow I need to get the ID of each posts, so it will only show the header of the post, which I'm hovering?

I hope someone understands me?

This is my site: [jasminstammler.ch](https://jasminstammler.ch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the posts header based on the post you are currently hovering.

```
$(this).find('.post-header').css('opacity', 1);
```

Then you need to add the mouseevents to the right container. On your site the `posts` container contains **all** posts, but you want to trigger the event for each post individually, so you need to attach the event to the `post-container` class.

Here is a working example:

```js
$('.post-container')
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('.post-header').css({'opacity': 1});
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('.post-header').css({'opacity': 0});
  });
```

```css
.post-container {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.post-header {
    color: red;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posts">
<div class="post-container">
  <h1 class="post-header">Header 1</h1>
  This is post 1
</div>

<div class="post-container">
  <h1 class="post-header">Header 2</h1>
  This is post 2
</div>


<div class="post-container">
  <h1 class="post-header">Header 3</h1>
  This is post 3
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it also possible to just have this effect on desktop and in max-width: 500px (mobile) to let the headertext be shown?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to use media queries in CSS and JS to determine the maxWidth of you window. 
#1 give your post-header an opacity of 1 in your css 
#2 then only run the function in js if that query is not matched.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d6983vt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    $('.post-container').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.post-header').show();
   }, function(){
       $('.post-header').hide();
    });

});
```

Here in the code `$(this)` will act on current dom which interacts with the JS or jQuery API only remaining are kept intact.

Comment: With this code, the title doesnt show up by hovering. Could it be because of "opacity: 0;" in post-header?

Comment: The opacity may be the issue but you have verify both your CSS and JS, visited your site it seems working. My suggestion create two classes and apply it based on hover action mouseenter, mouseleave